# jQuery-ui dialog automatically gets z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, z-index

I have an element named `tools` with `z-index: 400000`. I want it to be on the top of all elements always. In addition there is a jQuery-ui dialog on the same page with options:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ stack: false, zIndex: 1000 });
```

first time that dialog opens i can see the `tool` element on top but since it closed and and open again, the dialog gets `400001` z-index automatically.

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think jquery dialog or modals are meant to float over all elements to serve its purpose. All the same you can try adding `!important` to the z-index css property of the `tools` element(s).
Example

```
.tools{
    z-index:40000 !important;
}
```

If it does not solve the situation, then you can simply extend the jquery dialog plugin and overwrite the behavior of automatically setting the z-index to be the largest of all.

Comment: Don't need test, adding `!important` will not solve the problem at all. but have thought about extending the plugin myself, Nevertheless i'll wait for more solutions because editing plugin is unwarranted.

Comment: I had a case where the top of a dialog was hidden behind a css menu. the tools class did not work for me but setting z-index on .ui-front did.

Comment: in the current version of 1.9.3, adding `!important` actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to replicate problem and dialog `z-index` always stays the same. Due to overlay position being fixed and filling full viewport, I found that had to make sure `tools` has position `relative, absolute, or fixed` in order to be visible when overlay is in place

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd4bZ/1/)

Comment: You're right, but tools has `absolute` position, it really works in your demo but not sure why it behave another way in my program

Comment: there must be some other  code causing the z-index change. jQueryUI doesn't seem to do it as witnessed in fiddle demo. Even placing `tool` dead center where dialog is , tools is visible

Comment: Yes, What i see is that it's working correctly, i'm just wonder if the `jQuery-ui` library is not the same, i'm using 1.9.2 (last version)

Comment: The strange issue is that each time i open the dialog in my program `z-index` grows up (Using Firebug), but in your demo no such thing happens.

Comment: can you post link to live page? I don't think is jQueryUI doing it

Comment: Live page needs authentication, how can i send you a private message ?

Comment: could find an empty chat room and let me know which one it is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21872/discussion-between-omid-amraei-and-charlietfl)